# Restore from an Azure Storage Explorer downloaded through Powershell failing

Tags: sql, azure, azure-powershell

[image]We receive weekly FULL and daily DIFF back ups from our hosted ERP quoting system provider.  We are using Powershell code and a task to download the most recent file from a blob container to a local server location we use for our back ups.

When I download the files from Azure Storage explorer manually and run the restore job it works fine.  When I run the restore job from the Powershell downloaded file i get an error.

.bak' is incorrectly formed and can not be read.

I cannot figure out why this is happening.  Anyone run into this and fix it?

Comment: Could you please provide the PowerShell script used to download blob?

Comment: Added the code we are using

Comment: Could you please check if you used the right blob?

Comment: Yes it is all the right blob.  When I run the powershell code myself and not through task scheduler it will work, but maybe something to do with task scheduler is causing it to not download right?